# Locations in a specific radius in order of distance

Tags: mongodb, morphia, database

I have a problem with morphia. I want to query locations, which are in a specific radius arround a location.

But I am not sure how to do so. If I am using "near(x,y,r)", I get lots of results (up to limit) in order of distance. But they're results out of my radius as well.

If I am using "within(x,y,r)" then I do get the results I want just in the wrong order. 
What can I use to get alle locations in that radius AND in order of distance?

Comment: What's your code look like? $near doesn't support radius according to [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/#_S_near). $centersphere does, but results need to be sorted/limited. Lots of good info on the docs for [2d Geospatial Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/).

Comment: In my code I am using morphia queries. Like "query.field("_location").near(r.getLongitude(), r.getLatitude(), radius);"

According to the [docs for morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Query#Geo-spatial) it is supposed to work.

Comment: Apparently, they're mapping it to $nearSphere if you look at the source for morphia. Do you have 2D indexes set up? Are they longitude, latitude? Also, r in [radians](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/nearsphere-returns-too-many-data-what-am-i-missing-am-i-wrong-is-it-a-bug-d)?

Comment: Yes, I do have indexes and the distance in radians, otherwise the "within" request wouldnt work either

Comment: Try it without using morphia by just using the mongo shell. I always use that as a debugging aid. Maybe it's something about morphia (I've never used it).